# How to narrow argument types if void is possible?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to write a function that optionally accepts a void.
how in the body can I check what came to me?
If I understand correctly, "void" is a type that, in principle, cannot be read.

```
const fn: <T>(a: T) => T extends void ? string : number = (a) => {
    if (typeof a === 'undefined' || a === undefined || a === null) {
        return '1'
    }
    return 1
}
```

writes an error

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'T extends void ? string : number'
```

but it definitely works, here is a usage example

```
Promise.resolve().then(
    Math.random() > 0.5 ?
        () => { } :
        () => 1
).then(fn)
```

tried overloading but it seems to be a dead end too

```
function fn1<T extends void>(a: T): string
function fn1<T>(a: T): number {
    if (typeof a === 'undefined' || a === undefined || a === null) {
        return '1'
    }
    return 1
}
```

Comment: I thought [`void`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#void) was only used for return types?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen well, so a function that returns "void" can be used in the callback chain

Comment: `void` is a weird type and you should probably not be accepting it?  Your code is treating it as if it's `undefined` or `null`, so maybe you can just use `undefined | null` instead?  It's distracting to ask about `void` because it brings up so many issues, none of which are what seems to be the point of your question.

Comment: (continued) The actual point of your question is described in [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912); if you want to use generic conditional return types you'll need something like type assertions.  Or you could change to overloads, but you have to do it correctly (you seem to think the implementation acts as a call signature, but it doesn't... you left one out.) Both approaches are shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NDeEVm). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?